# Set variable not been read from .emacs

Tags: customize, backup

I've set some variables (kept-new-versions, for one) to a higher number (10, it was 2) since I don't mind having a handful of backup files in my dir.

I did it using C-h v and customizing the variable. They get written into the .emacs file, but after restarting the program, they are at their previous values (2,2).

I have noticed the message "kept-new-versions is a variable defined in `files.el'." and I wonder, whether this is overriding my .emacs settings. Otherwise, I have no idea what it could be.

What I have in my `.emacs`:

```
 '(version-control t)     ;; Use version numbers for backups.
 '(kept-new-versions 10)  ;; Number of newest versions to keep.
 '(kept-old-versions 0)   ;; Number of oldest versions to keep.
 '(delete-old-versions t) ;; Don't ask to delete excess backup versions.
 '(backup-by-copying t)  ;; Copy all files, don't rename them.
```

I expect this to create a backup file after each save, but not more than 10 of them.

Comment: Can you confirm whether the quoted settings are within a `(custom-set-variables ...)` form?

Comment: @phils: yes, they are. But problem is solved, using answer below.

Comment: That suggests to me that something is wrong with your config. One possibility is that you've told Emacs to write customized values to a separate `custom-file`, but that you're not `load`ing that file in your `.emacs`. Or perhaps an error is occurring on start-up before your `custom-set-variables` is processed. In any case, I suspect the root cause of your problem is still in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set variables in Emacs use:

```
(setq version-control t)     ;; Use version numbers for backups.
(setq kept-new-versions 10)  ;; Number of newest versions to keep.
(setq kept-old-versions 0)   ;; Number of oldest versions to keep.
(setq delete-old-versions t) ;; Don't ask to delete excess backup versions.
(setq backup-by-copying t)  ;; Copy all files, don't rename them.
```

You can also `setq` multiple variables, as in

```
(setq version-control t
      kept-new-versions 10)
```

For more info see [the documentation here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/Using-setq.html).